# How to use AES_Encrypt when load data infile query in my SQL

Tags: mysql, aes

I am trying to load a data file but I want the data encrypted using the `AES_Encrypt` function.

I read about the below usage but I am unsure how to go about using it and what do I set as what.

```
myTable(myname,@mypass) SET mypass=AES_ENCRYPT(@mypass,'key:test');
```

EDIT: I tried doing this but it didn't work:

load data local in file 'thefilepath' into table mytable_new_copy(@sale) SET sale=AES_ENCRYPT(@sale,'test')

Comment: Please show what you tried, and we can point out how you went wrong and show how to correct it.

Comment: load data local in file '**thefilepath**' into 
table mytable_new_copy(@sale) SET sale=AES_ENCRYPT(@sale,'test')

Comment: That is what I tried with the file path removed. The file path is correct as I have tested it without using the AES_ENcrypt

Comment: Please edit that into your question, code is hard to read in comments.